# type 'DocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: database, firebase, flutter

**This is my profile Page**
I also tried snapshot.data()
and also tried converting it to Map data by seeing some other StackOverflow answers.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

The error is in line number 63.
I am not sure how to get that correct. Actually, in the tutorial, they showed for from document but I have to use FromMap But I am not sure How to use that

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

import 'package:justpoll/screens/profile/edit_profile.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/screens/profile/profile_nav_bar/settings.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/screens/profile/profile_nav_bar/help.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/Constants.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/libmodels/user_model.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/libservices/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/screens/home_page/nav.dart';

class Profile2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String profileId;

  Profile2({this.profileId});
  @override
  _Profile2State createState() => new _Profile2State();
}

final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

class _Profile2State extends State<Profile2> {
  buildProfileButton() {
    return Text("profile Button");
  }

  Column buildCountColumn(String lable, int count) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          count.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
          child: Text(
            lable,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 15.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  buiildProfileHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: userRef.doc(widget.profileId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }

        UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data.data);

        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            buildCountColumn("posts", 0),
                            buildCountColumn("follower", 0),
                            buildCountColumn("following", 0),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            buildProfileButton(),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.username,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.bio,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: MyColors.black),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EditProfile(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.edit,
                color: MyColors.black,
                size: 26,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: new Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsScreen()),
              );
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
            title: new Text('Bookmarks'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.drafts),
            title: new Text('Drafts'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.archive),
            title: new Text('Archive'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.help),
            title: new Text('help'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HelpPage()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          buiildProfileHeader(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And This is my user module**

```
class UserModel {
  String email;
  String uid;
  String username;
  String name;
  DateTime timestamp;
  bool isPrivate;
  String photoUrl;
  String gender;
  String bio;
  String birthday;
  Map followers;
  Map following;

  UserModel({
    this.email,
    this.uid,
    this.username,
    this.timestamp,
    this.name,
    this.photoUrl,
    this.isPrivate,
    this.gender,
    this.bio,
    this.birthday,
    this.followers,
    this.following,
  });

  Map toMap(UserModel user) {
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();

    data["uid"] = user.uid;
    data["username"] = user.username;
    data["email"] = user.email;
    data['name'] = user.name;
    data['photoUrl'] = user.photoUrl;
    data["timestamp"] = user.timestamp;
    data["isPrivate"] = user.isPrivate;
    data["gender"] = user.gender;
    data["bio"] = user.bio;
    data["birthday"] = user.birthday;
    data["followers"] = user.followers;
    data["following"] = user.following;
    return data;
  }

  UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mapData) {
    this.uid = mapData["uid"];
    this.username = mapData["username"];
    this.email = mapData["email"];
    this.name = mapData["name"];
    this.isPrivate = mapData["isPrivate"];
    this.gender = mapData["gender"];
    this.photoUrl = mapData["photoUrl"];
    this.bio = mapData["bio"];
    this.birthday = mapData["birthday"];
    this.followers = mapData["followers"];
    this.following = mapData["following"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Check type of `snapshot.data.data`. You can do this by debug your app.

Comment: What do you mean? 
Can you please Specify it for me

Comment: try logging the snapshot data; like `print(snapshot.data.data())`

Comment: Its showing null

Comment: Ok. First check whether the doc exists using `if (snapshot.data.exists)` if it's true -> `print(snapshot.data.data())`. and put this on line 62

Comment: Still it is not working

Comment: @RamithKS Did you solve this error? I am also getting the same thing while fetching the data from firestore DB

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
var DocData = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;
```

This gives you the data which can be accessed by

```
DocData['fieldname'];
```

you can use the fields like this

Comment: really helpfull. Thanks

Comment: this one works var DocData = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data.data());
```

```
buiildProfileHeader() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: userRef.doc(widget.profileId).get(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return circularProgress();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Something went wrong");
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
        UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(data);
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            buildCountColumn("posts", 0),
                            buildCountColumn("follower", 0),
                            buildCountColumn("following", 0),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            buildProfileButton(),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.username,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.bio,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: yeah, I already tried it but still, it's not working.
Please, someone, help me with .it

Comment: @RamithKS I edited your `buiildProfileHeader` method. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks but still have some error 

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#df189):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("uid")

Comment: or anyone knows the solution?